# How to show menu when clicked on View with background image?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have made 6 Views in linear layout. I'll post here only one and XML code for it is:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewMeni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/meni"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="meniClick"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I display the defined menu when clicking on viewMeni ?

Comment: This questions was flagged for content. Could you please elaborate on your exact problem? What precisely are you expecting to happen when you click on viewMeni?

Comment: I expect that when I press viewMeni main menu opens. viewMeni has PNG image in the background, so I wanna make some kind of clickable picture with menu symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
first find that view in your activity ... and then used registerforcontextmenu(yourname);
then 

     @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);       
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.favourite, menu);

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();      
            int position = info.position;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.connect:              

                    return true;
                case R.id.mark:
                    return true;
                case R.id.delete:               
                    return true;                
                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```